# Can mobs go through doors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if mobs can go through doors or not. It's the difference between me just putting up a door to my house, or putting up dirt instead.

Answer (score 16):

- Zombies can [batter down wooden doors](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz_zx47eix0&list=UUH-_hzb2ILSCo9ftVSnrCIQ&index=7&feature=plcp) in hard & hardcore modes.
- Villagers can open and close wooden doors to go through them.
- All mobs will walk through *open* doors.

Comment: If this answer has helped you, click the tick to the left to accept it. You'll get reputation!

Comment: Note that mobs might be able to go through doors, if there is more than one door into the house. This is a very old bug. This will mostly just cause you being able to go to bed.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be unable?

Comment: @fredley yeah, I wrote that before my first coffee of the day :-)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I feel your pain, I woke up to no coffee in the house this morning...

Comment: The battering down of doors is only on hard or hardcore. Zombies will not do it on easy or normal.

Comment: Really? Oh man. And here I thought I was safe.

Answer (score -1):

Mobs can go through  open doors if that's what you mean... In 1.2 zombies will be able to break doors down. In the snapshots right now, they can break wood and Iron doors, but the iron door breaking is a glitch and they will only be able to break wooden ones in the official release.